# Removing UIImageView added programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I know there are many threads about this and i read them but i couldn't make it work. This is my code

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *advertiseView;

- (void)startShowingImage
{
    _advertiseView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80,320,150,97)];
    _advertiseView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blocksAd.png"];

    [self.view addSubview:_advertiseView];
    NSLog(@"startShowing");
}

- (void)stopShowingImage
{
    NSLog(@"stopShowing");
    [_advertiseView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

i put `NSLogs` to check whether the methods are called and they are, but the image after it's first shown never disappears.
Any advice about this?

Comment: The problem is probably not in the code you've shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that both the addSubview and removeFromSuperView are called in main thread

Check that startShowingImage is only called once, otherwise you have orphaned UIImageViews that you can never remove

```
- (void)startShowingImage
{
    if (self.advertiseView) {
        self.advertiseView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80,320,150,97)];
        self.advertiseView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blocksAd.png"];

        [self.view addSubview:self.advertiseView];
        NSLog(@"startShowing");
    }
}
```

Use property syntax unless you specifically need otherwise to avoid problems

Comment: I found the method to Show was called twice that's why the image couldn't be deleted! Because there were 2!! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If `NSLog(@"stopShowing")` is definitely being called, then the only problem I think you might be having that would lead to `removeFromSuperview` not working is that you're not making your change (a UI update) on the main thread.

Try this instead:

```
[_advertiseView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(removeFromSuperview) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```